# Combine 3 mutually-exclusive columns in a dataset for Python

Tags: python, multiple-columns

Hey folks good morning,

This is my very first message here and please consider I am a novice in Python.
I was given a dataset within which I have 3 mutually exclusive columns such as the following example:

```py
ID  White   Black   Red

1    Yes     No     No

2     No    Yes     No

3     No     No     Yes

4     No    Yes     No
```

As a result, what I would like to have is:

```py
ID  Color

1    White

2    Black  

3    Red

4    Black
```

I haven't found a conclusive solution on this, despite my reserach on Stack website. Anyone willing to suggest a way?
Thanks
PS: sorry for the message formatting..!!

Comment: How is data stored? In csv? excel? rdbms? Which library/package are you using?

Comment: Data are stored in csv format

Comment: Remove tag “Combine”, it is Apples FRP lib

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col='ID')

cols = df.columns

def get_color(row):
    for col in cols:
        if row[col] == 'Yes':
            return col

df['Color'] = df.apply(get_color, axis=1)

print(df[['Color']])
```

```
    Color
ID       
1   White
2   Black
3     Red
4   Black
```

Answer (score 0):

The key here is `stack` if you replace `No` values with `NaN` which will be ignored by stack:

```
df[df == 'No'] = np.NaN
resul = df.set_index('ID').stack().reset_index().drop(columns=0).rename(
                   columns={'level_1': 'Color'})
```

It gives as expected:

```
   ID  Color
0   1  White
1   2  Black
2   3    Red
3   4  Black
```